# dynamically set height of chart when printing Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am using `Hightcharts.js` 4.0.1

It works great, however the size of the chart when printing needs to be different than the size of the chart when displayed on the HTML document.

How can I set it so that when the chart prints, it goes to 100% of the page width and height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `chart.setSize()` method in `beforePrint` and `afterPrint` events callback functions to change your chart size so it will be printed on whole page:

```
chart: {
  width: 1000,
  height: 600,
  events: {
    beforePrint: function() {
      this.setSize(1000, 1000);
    },
    afterPrint: function() {
      this.setSize(1000, 600,false);
      this.redraw();
    }
  }
},
```

Here you can see an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/usw1hfd2/1/

Comment: This works great, however for some reason on this fiddle it doesn't resize after the printing is done. the beforePrint function works fine. Any idea why that would be? Otherwise works perfect. Tku!

Comment: I am not able to recreate your issue, in my case chart is resizing after print. Could you give more information about browser you are using?

Comment: It works now - sorry, had a little bug on something Thank you!